# Calculating charge density $\rho(r)$ using Gauss law (both forms)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, gauss-law

Below is a question given in my assignment. I tried applying Gauss law in both forms, differential and surface integral form. But both there is a difference by a factor of $2$. **Is the differential form not applicable here?**

> There is a spherical charge distribution where Potential varies as $V = V_0r^3$. We have to find $\rho(r)$, ie charge density.

$\mathbf{Try\ \ 1}:\ \ \ \ \nabla\cdot\vec{E} = \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}$

Since $V = V_o r^3$,

$$\vec{E} = -3V_or^2\hat{r}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial(-3V_o r^2)}{\partial r} = \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}$$

$$\boxed{\rho(r) = -6V_o \epsilon_o r}$$

$\mathbf{Try\ \ 2}:\ \ \ \ \Phi=\int_S\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}$

Since $V = V_o r^3$,

$$\vec{E} = -3V_or^2\hat{r}$$
$$\phi = \vec{E}\cdot 4\pi r^2 \\ =-12V_o\pi r^4$$
$$\implies Q_{enc}=-12V_o\epsilon_o\pi r^4$$

Now, $\rho = \dfrac{dQ}{dV}$, where V is Volume.

$$\implies \rho = \dfrac{-48V_o\epsilon_or^3dr}{4\pi r^2 dr}\\ 
\boxed{\rho(r)= -12V_o \epsilon_o r}$$

**Q.** Is the differential form not applicable here? or am I applying it incorrectly?

I do not seek answer to numerical question, only whether the approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential and integral forms should in principle always lead to the same result, since they are related to each other via Gauss's theorem. (e.g. see [What are the differences between the differential and integral forms of (e.g. Maxwell's) equations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256739/what-are-the-differences-between-the-differential-and-integral-forms-of-e-g-ma/256748) ).

In this case you have not applied the differential form correctly, because you have used an incorrect form for divergence in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: I understoot it now! But how do we know which form of divergence to use? Do we have to learn the different expressions fo div in different coordinates?

Comment: @MaxPayne You (correctly) assumed spherical symmetry *and* used spherical coordinates. Therefore you should use the expression for divergence in spherical coordinates. Actually you could have gone straight to the charge density using Poisson's equation $\nabla^2 V = -\rho/\epsilon_0$ (in spherical coordinates).

Answer (score 2):

$\nabla \cdot \vec E(r) = \dfrac {1}{r^2} \dfrac {d(r^2 E)}{dr} \ne \dfrac{dE}{dr}$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: But how do we know which form of divergence to use? Do we have to learn the different expressions fo div in different coordinates?

Comment: In this case you have radial symmetry which means that you should be using spherical coordinates. The hint is in the equation for the potential.

Comment: must we learn the different formulas for different coordinates? or can we quickly derive it when solving problem?

Comment: For most students the formulae a re derived at least once but if you look at this list you need either to remember them or have them listed.  http://web.mit.edu/8.02-esg/notes/coordops.pdf